# How do I avoid the prompt: Multiple identities can be used for authentication?

Tags: 16.04, server, sudo

I'm setting up a continuous deployment user, `agent`, on my Ubuntu Server 16.04 instance.

He is in the `sudo` group. He has also been added to `visudo` as such:

```
agent ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl
```

I want him to be able to start and stop `systemd` services without a interactive console session.

However when he executes the command `systemctl stop my.service`, he gets the following message:

```
Authentication is required to stop 'my.service'.

Multiple identities can be used for authentication:

1.  Ubuntu (ubuntu)
2.  ,,, (user1)
3.  ,,, (user2)
4.  ,,, (agent) 

Choose identity to authenticate as (1-4):
```

This defeats my CI/CD software.

Is there any way that I can prevent this screen from showing up? My `sudoers` file is default, excepting that one modification:

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

agent ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl
```